# Awk script system date and pipe to html page?

Tags: html, awk

I want to write an awk script to display the system date and pipe it to HTML page.

This is my AWK script I wrote
date.awk:

```
BEGIN { "date" | getline; system("date >> myfile.html") }
```

From the above `awk` `script`, I can append the date but want to display the updated date only once. The past written date values are also been printed when I refresh the page. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong? 
When I refresh my browser my current date should appear in the html page. Whenever I run the `awk script`, the new system date has to be updated in my html page.

myfile.html

```
<table>
<tr><td>Chocolates</td><td>Hersheys</td></tr>
<tr><td>Biscuits</td><td>Oreo</td></tr>
</table>
```

Date should print here using the AWK script.

Comment: why you don't use a dinamic web language as php or perl,python and so on?

Comment: Yes. I can do using php. <? system ("date") ?> will print the system date next to the html table. But I wanted to know the code, when I run awk script the date should pipe to the html next to the table.

Comment: myfile.html is not a well-formed HTML document.  Is that intentional?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. My requirement is to print date after the html content. I have just created the above html and once I execute in browser, it displays the content. Then my date should print after the html content. The main thing is I wanted to write an AWK script which when executed, AWK script will be running behind and once I refresh, the browser will contact the AWK script and prints the date below the HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

The content shown for myfile.html is not a well formed HTML document.  Simply appending the date to a well formed HTML document is not really a viable solution.  Normally you need html and body tags surrounding the date.  The solution below does not work for a well-formed HTML document, but that does not appear to be what the question asks for.  This solution really can only be expected to point towards using awk to filter the old date before appending another date.

The script appends data to the html file but does not remove previously appended data.  There are several ways to solve the problem, but whatever method is chosen, the solution must remove the previous date before appending a new date.  The script fragment supplied in the question is so terse as to make difficult forming an answer that takes the context of the problem into consideration, but here goes:

```
FILE="myfile.html"
awk \
  -v DATE="`date`" \
  -v FILE="${FILE}.new" \
  'BEGIN \
   { PATT = gensub(/[[:alpha:][:digit:]]/, ".", "g", DATE) }
   $0 !~ ("^" PATT "$") \
   { print >FILE }
   END \
   { print DATE > FILE; close(FILE) }
  ' "${FILE}"
mv "${FILE}.new" "${FILE}"
```

PATT is a regular expression constructed from a sample date.  You could make a better pattern with specific knowledge of what the date actually looks like.  If `date` output "Wed Apr 29 09:23:22 CDT 2015", PATT would be "... ... .. ..:..:.. ... ....".  It is a crude pattern that could be improved upon, but is still likely to match only the appended date.

Basically every line not matching the date pattern in PATT is output to a new file called myfile.html.new.  After all the old lines are copied to the new file a new date is appended, then the new file replaces the old one.  One would hope there aren't other scripts that update myfile.html while this script runs.

Comment: Hi kbulgrien, I really appreciate your prompt response. Thank you so much. I will surely try the above script. I will revert back if I have anymore queries asap.